# Retrieve row values from the 3rd column of table

Tags: jquery

No classes/id on table or plugins. Just simple table with 4 columns and 8 rows with some dummy values in it.

How can I get row values of 3rd column of a table.

anyone please write some jquery syntax.

Anyone know any online tutorial for table manipulation in jquery. No plugins?

Comment: Without an id or class, the only other selector to identify the table would be the `table` element itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr><td>One</td><td>Red</td></tr>
<tr><td>Two</td><td>Blue</td></tr>
<tr><td>Three</td><td>Green</td></tr>
</table>​
```

This will extract the values in the third table row element and put it into an array.

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    var values = [];
    $('table tr:nth-child(3) td').each( function() {
        values.push($(this).html());
    });
    console.log(values);
}​);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AQcgm/

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your table is semantically intact (i.e: tr > td), you can use a jQuery `each` loop to grab the third td in each tr. See http://jsfiddle.net/sLtya/

Answer (score 0):

If you had a 4 column, 8 row table, and you wanted to get the text out of the third column from each row, you could use the following:

```
 $('table tr td:nth-child(3)').text()
```

Or, if you wanted to perform an action against each column from the result, like change the background color:

```
 $('table tr td:nth-child(3)').css('backgroundColor', '#efefef');
```

Hope this helps. I realize the question was asked awhile ago, but I was looking on how to do this and couldn't find a solution easily, so hopefully me sharing this will help someone else that's looking how to do this.